# Count item after joining two table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables,
First is  **Product** table

```
 +-----------+------+-----+------------+
 | id  | pnum | year |month|date        |
 +-----------+------+-----+------------+
 |12   |  S5 | 2021 | 2   | 2021-02-21 |
 |12   |  S5 | 2021 | 2   | 2021-02-22 |
 |12   |  S5 | 2021 | 2   | 2021-02-23 |
 |33   |  A55| 2021 | 3   | 2021-03-01 |
 |44   |  B1 | 2021 | 6   | 2021-06-01 |
```

Second is **Deal** table

```
 +-----------+------+-----+------------+
 | id  | pnum| year |month|date        |
 +-----------+------+-----+------------+
 |12   |  S5 | 2021 | 2   | 2021-02-28 |
 |12   |  S5 | 2021 | 2   | 2021-02-01 |
 |33   |  A55| 2021 | 3   | 2021-03-01 |
```

I need a result which can tell me how many product got launch
for a year_month and count of deal in first 15 days or in next 15 days

```
 +----------- +------------+----------------+--------------------+
 | num | count| year-month |deal_in_first15 |deal_after_first15 |
 +----------- +------+-----+-------------------------------------
 |S5   |  3   | 2021-02    |      1         |       1           |
 |A55  |  1   | 2021-03    |      1         |       0           |
```

I was trying to do it like below

```
 select * from Product p inner join Deal d on
 p.num=d.num AND p.id=d.id AND p.month=d.month
```

but it is not helping me to get exact result as intended.

I have some java and python background and not expert in sql hence applying count and case statement is  not working out.

Comment: you will need two diffrent queries for it.. count of deal in first 15 days or in next 15 days is altogether a different creteria

Comment: @nikhilsugandh no need for 2 queries; conditional aggregation exists.

Comment: 44   |  B1 this should also be added in the output as it got launched  in2021-06-01

Comment: No 44 | B1  need to ignore as it does not have any relationship in second table

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try to use the condition aggregate function in subquery then do `JOIN`

```
select p.pnum ,
       COUNT(*) count,
       FORMAT(p.[date],'yyyy-MM') 'year-month',
       deal_in_first15 ,
       deal_after_first15
from Product p 
inner join (
    SELECT id ,
        pnum ,
        month,
        year ,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(day,[date]) < 15 THEN 1 END) deal_in_first15 ,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(day,[date]) >= 15 THEN 1 END) deal_after_first15 
    FROM Deal 
    GROUP BY id ,pnum ,month,year
) d on
 p.pnum=d.pnum AND p.id=d.id AND p.month=d.month
 group by  FORMAT(p.[date],'yyyy-MM') ,
          p.pnum,
          deal_in_first15 ,
          deal_after_first15
```

I think there is another way might you want, using two subquery then `JOIN`

```
select p.pnum ,
       p.cnt 'count',
       CONCAT(p.year,'-',FORMAT(p.month,'0#')) 'year-month',
       deal_in_first15 ,
       deal_after_first15
from (
    SELECT id ,
        pnum ,
        month,
        year,
        count(*) cnt
    FROM Product
    GROUP BY  id ,
        pnum ,
        month,
        year
) p 
inner join (
    SELECT id ,
        pnum ,
        month,
        year ,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(day,[date]) < 15 THEN 1 END) deal_in_first15 ,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(day,[date]) >= 15 THEN 1 END) deal_after_first15 
    FROM Deal 
    GROUP BY id ,pnum ,month,year
) d on
 p.pnum=d.pnum 
 AND p.id=d.id 
 AND p.month=d.month
 AND p.year=d.year
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b2beeb676c636de1f4cc150f576179a8)

**Note**

I would use the `year` column to be `JOIN` condition. otherwise, the result will be wrong when you cross-year meet the same month.

Comment: For me it worked , I tried with your first solution

Comment: took year  too in group by in first solution.
if you don't mind can you explain performance wise, which one is the best solution first or second ?

Comment: @punam if you are considering performance it depends on your execution plan, but I will vote the first query it simpler than the second.

Answer (score -1):

This is it:

```
select pnum,cnt,sum(mn1),sum(mn2) from  (select  d."pnum",(select count(*) from Product p where p."pnum"=d."pnum"
                ) cnt,
case when
EXTRACT(DAY FROM d."date")<=15 then sum(1) else sum(0) end mn1 , 
case when
EXTRACT(DAY FROM d."date")>15 then sum(1) else sum(0) end mn2,
d."year"||'-'||d."month"
from deal d  
group by 1,d."year"||'-'||d."month",d."date")abc group by 1,2;
```

please check at:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/3bad9/18

Comment: Perhaps because OP is using SQL Server, not Postgres?

Comment: Convert it to SQL SERVER then na  ..there exists all types of equivalents...